# PanGestureRecognizer inside ListView (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: android, ios, listview, xamarin.forms, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm making a messaging app in Xamarin.Forms (Android and iOS).

Messages are being shown in a `ListView`.

Now I want to add a new feature. When I drag the message balloon to the side, it shows the message info.

The user holds the message, drags to right or left.

- If he drags enough, a **new page with the info** shows
- If he releases before this "threshold", the balloon **bounces back to its place**.

I tried implementing this with a `PanGestureRecognizer` (PGR in this context) on the balloon, but it worked partially.

### Android

I can drag, release, release before the threshold, and it works! But if I drag vertically while dragging to horizontally, the `ListView` "steals" the pan gesture, the PGR "forgets" it and doesn't return any event. So the balloon just keeps there, a bit to the side.

[image: Intially] -- Initial state.

[image: Dragging right] -- Dragging the message to the right

[image: Already released] -- I've already released the message, but it is still to the right.

This doesn't happen if I release the finger without dragging down.

It may look obvious: "*Why don't you just make it go back when the finger is "forgotten"?*"
Because when the problem happens, it doesn't generate another event. (And the `ListView` doesn't have the `Scrolled` event as the `ScrollView`)

### iOS

When I try to use the PGR, the `ListView` doesn't work. But the side drag works. Looks like the PGRs are grabbing the pan gesture always first.

Is there any way to make the PGR and the `ListView` work simultaneously?

Comment: You want to push a new page to show this info or the place like ListView's [Context Actions](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#contextactions)? Please post some images to clarify your requirement.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT Screenshotting and editting my post, hold on

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT done

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm experiencing the exact same thing, ListView is stealing my touch events and I have found no way to detect when that occurs.

Comment: @Mort Sorry, I didn't found it. I don't even work with Xamarin anymore

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you can try adding:

```
Application.Current.On<iOS>().SetPanGestureRecognizerShouldRecognizeSimultaneously(true)
```

References: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2299#issuecomment-399578363
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/application-pan-gesture

For Android i made a workaround with timer:

```
private System.Threading.Timer timer;

private void PanGesture_PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
  var statusType = e.StatusType;

  if (statusType != GestureStatus.Started && timer == null)
  {
      // after gesture was broken down, next event will be with wrong 
      // status, like the gesture is continues. So, reset status to Started,
      // consider it is new gesture:
      statusType = GestureStatus.Started;
  }

  var slidingView = yourView;

  switch (statusType)
  {
      case GestureStatus.Started:
          // do any initializations..
          timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => {
              finishTranslation(slidingView);
          });
          break;
      case GestureStatus.Running:
          {
              // do any animations..
              timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), TimeSpan.Zero);
          }
          break;
  }
}

private void finishTranslation(View slidingView)
{
  timer = null;
  // finish your animation
}
```

But problem with tap gesture still here((